# power function K&R

Tags: c, function

Hello I am beginner in C and I am reading 1.7 functions in K&R book. Below code is taken as is from the book.

```
int power(int m, int n);

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;++i)
        printf("%d %d %d \n",i,power(2,i),power(-3,i));
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int n)
{
    int i, p;
    p=1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
        p=p*base;

    return p;
}
```

I can not understand how this code works, especially this part:

```
int power(int base, int n)
{
    int i, p;
    p=1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
        p=p*base;

    return p;
}
```

Here, where is returned `p`?
How this whole code raises number in power? And, relationship between these two parts of the code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Walk through the code with a pencil and paper and some test starting values with known answers. Then walk through the code in a debugger, line by line, examining variable contents to see if your paper suspicions were correct. Debuggers are *fantastic* for understanding how a program actually works.

Comment: Do you understand what it means when a function returns a value? You might want to review the basics in the book. Also, is the code taken from the book? It doesn't look like good code to me.

Comment: @FeiXiang yeah its from book. as i understand it returns to main right?

Comment: Your question seems to be asking "how does a function work" and maybe "how does a for loop work", and maybe even "what does it mean to raise an integer `base` to a positive integer power `n`".   Those are really issues best covered by reading a textbook and working through the examples.  K&R has a tendency to assume some basic knowledge of programming; it explains the mechanics of C well, but doesn't necessarily explain the mechanics of programming in general.  Which programming languages do you know?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am new this is first time I began I dont know other programing languages at all and I am very interested in programming.so i am very happy that i started learning this.about for loop i understand how it works i read it already.how to raise in power i also know how it happens in math.i know math very well.but i can not understand very well  exactly in this code order of the steps if you understand me

Answer (score 3):

The code multiplies the base n times, which is essentially the definition of an integer exponent. What's important to recognize is that the loop executes n times, and each time it is multiplying p by the base.

Comment: so second part of this code multiplies base n times right?and there is written return p,where is it returned?and what does then first part of this code?

Comment: The *first part* of the function code declares the local variables and initilializes `p` to the value `1`.

Comment: @ႨႰႠႩႪႨ When a function returns, the control goes to the line that called the function.